# Extract Max Length of allowed string from Regex object

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to extract a max length of an allowed string from a regex pattern once it has been loaded into a C# `Regex` object?

If I have a Regex string defined as `@"^[A-Z0-9]{0,20}$"`, I could use string manipulation to get the maximum allowed length of `20`.

However is there a way I can get that more easily, for instance via a `Regex` object as follows:

```
var r = new Regex(@"^[A-Z0-9]{0,20}$");
// var max = r.MaxLength;
```

**Update**

To set some context, I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 application in which we use a `RegexValidationAttribute` to provide input validation our view models.

What I would like to do is override that attribute such that I can add a Custom metadata property which contains the maximum allowed length of the string, parsed from the regex string. In my string Editor Template, I will then grab the custom metadata value, and add a `maxlength=""` attribute to the html `<input>` tag.
Now I know I could just add a `StringLengthAttribute` and do it that way, but then I have to remember to keep the regex length and string length in sync. And with more than 1000+ models I want to de-duplicate the effort required.

Comment: Use another regex to parse previous one.

Comment: Can you supply an example?

Comment: there's no property that I know of, where you could read from how long a string may be, and I also guess it isn't implemented too. what you could do is, match it against your string and give out the count of the matched characters, if you are sure that there is a limit given - and that there is a match. the problem is that you can have as many character limits as you want in a regex pattern, so theres just not one actual limit -- what revo means is parse the 20 out of your sample regex with another regex

Comment: here: to get the numbers out of the braces - \{\d+?\,(\d+?)\} - or respectively \{\d+?\,(\d+?)\}$ for the last possible limit

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Could you add an usecase?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Take a regex like `.*` the length could be 0 to infinite. As long it's as simple as your example, I'd go with something like @revo's suggestion (supplied by prizm). (That would fail if the regex for example was something like `(\w\d){1,20}` though, since that could be up to 40 characters long.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to extract a max length of an allowed string from a regex pattern once it has been loaded into a C# `Regex` object?

No. The [Regex class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) have no built-in field/method that does the work.

One *could* write a method that would try to compute the maximum theoretical length of a match, it would work for simple regexes like the one you mentioned but as soon as multiple alternatives will show up and/or length quantifier (`+`/`*`) the calculation of the theoretical max length would be a nightmare.