# check if regex pattern is length restricted

Tags: regex

Thought this is a simple question but could not find a simple answer.

I need to validate data passing between services according to some restrictions.
one of the restrictions is that each string will have some defined(not necessarily directly) maximum length.

one of the restrictions being used is regex pattern restriction.
 for example: 
`pattern=".*\.."`
will not be length restricted. because can match `hey.` or `heeeey.` or string with any length of characters ending with `.`

`pattern="\d{2,5}"` is length restricted because this string maximum length is 5.

is there is some utility, script, or function to check if a given regex pattern is length restricted or I have to write my own script?

Comment: @AlexShesterov is it is length restricted to a maximum of 255 characters.

Comment: Related question, but not quite a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022278/extract-max-length-of-allowed-string-from-regex-object

Comment: @AlexShesterov thanks for the reference. if you know some tool that does the job it will be very appreciated. someone must have already done this before.

Comment: another comment to make this question active again

Answer (score -1):

Let me rephrase your question:

> Is the question if a regular grammer describes an infinite language decidable?

The answer to this question is yes ([more details here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55592/proof-that-whether-a-regular-language-is-finite-is-decidable#:%7E:text=Generate%20all%20of%20the%20strings,then%20the%20language%20is%20finite.)). For a finite state automata (which is equivilant to a regular grammer or a regular expression) to accept a inifinite language it needs to contain a cycle. Since a FSA can be represented as a graph, you just need check if it is a DAG or not. Is there an algorithm that already does that? I would be surprised since it took me a long time just to find a source to for the claim that the problem is decidable.

Comment: A lot of words, but no relevant info.

Comment: I know you would perfer a pice of code that you can copy/paste. Unfortunately this is not always available. I hope that this response still gives you the key words that you can search for while implementing your code.